# How to gracefully shutdown mongoDB in k8s

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

Im running MongoDB replica set on K8s. I create replicaset with the k8s internal dns records. MongoDB can handle SIGTERM signal to graceful shutdown by itself. Problem is, that in pod's 'terminating' state, k8s endpoints are deleted, but graceful shutdown is not complete yet in this phase, so this replica is cut out from the replica set and graceful shutdown cannot be performed. Is there any way to hold the endpoints for a while (something like terminationGracePeriodSeconds, but for EPs)? It is problem especially when we are talking about primary replica.

Note: Replica set used in my description is always MongoDB replica set, not k8s replica set.

Comment: what is the error here, eg. mongodb reports error during the shutdown, or data corrupted when restart?

Comment: Cut the network is the same case, from the view of the cluster, like sigkill on the replica. So if it's primary and writeConcern is set to lesser number than replica count in the whole cluster, some data could be probably lost.

Comment: when that happened there will be a log, did you see any of such log in any of your mongodb instance and can you paste it in your question if any?